# How to store preferences in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app users can log in using Firebase Auth.

My goal is to synchronize between devices certain preferences of user (key-value pairs)

Can it be done by firebase? Firebase analytics has ability to assign "user-properties", but how to retrieve them?

Comment: you can use Firebase Database , more info here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: if you are looking for syncronization storage system without write your server, this is better.